# Bring all community users to one permission profile and license

Tags: community, lightning-experience, customer-community, experience-cloud, partner-communities

**Background**

We currently have multiple permission profile and licenses for external users which makes it quite complex to maintain these. We want to have one permission profile and user license (customer community license) in the end so that it is easier to maintain and cheaper because we can get rid of the partner community licenses.

**Things to consider**

- We have different profiles for each community
- We have different profiles for different languages and of course after having everyone on one profile the community should still be accessible in different languages
- We have Customer Community Licenses and Partner Community Licenses

**ToDos**

validate if this is possible, if yes then what would be the strategy to achieve this.

Comment: If your intention is to cut costs, then you need to validate whether moving to Customer Community Licenses is a feasible idea. Customer Community Licenses and Partner Community Licenses have different purposes, allowed objects etc.

If you want to minimize complexity, then the question is whether moving everything to a single profile & permission set wouldn't give unnecessary permissions to users that are not supposed to have them. What kind of personas are in you org?

Comment: My intention is that we as a team realised we are not actually using the feature of Partner Community license, at the same time we can achieve same with customer community license. So biggest challenge here is migrating the Partner community users to Customer community user.